# Redis autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, redis

How can I implement an autocomplete using redis?

Say for example I have an array `["alfred","joel","jeff","addick"]`. When I type `a` I get `["alfred", "addick"]`

I hope you get the point. How can I implement this using redis commands efficiently(if possible but I think it is). It would be great if I could get some simple commands I can try out via telnet to mimic this behaviour.

Thanks

P.S: Merry x-mas to all of you :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're dealing with a large data set, I would suggest considering implementing this as a trie.  I have thrown together a small bit of Ruby that would do this:

```rb
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'redis'
    
    class RedisTrie
      TERMINAL = '+'
    
      def initialize(prefix)
        @prefix = prefix
        @r = Redis.new
      end
    
      def add_word(word)
        w = word.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/, '')
        key = "#{@prefix}:"
    
        w.each_char do |c|
          @r.zset_add key, c.bytes.first, c
          key += c
        end
    
        @r.zset_add key, 0, TERMINAL
      end
    
      def add_words(*words)
        words.flatten.compact.each {|word| add_word word}
      end
    
      def suggest(text)
        @r.zset_range("#{@prefix}:#{text}", 0, -1).map do |c|
          (c == TERMINAL) ? text : suggest(text + c)
        end.flatten
      end
    end
    
    rt = RedisTrie.new('trie')
    
    rt.add_words %w( apple automobile carwash oil-change cranky five ruthie axe auto )
    
    p rt.suggest(ARGV.shift.to_s)
```

For example:

```rb
    $ ruby RedisTrie.rb
    ["apple", "auto", "automobile", "axe", "carwash", "cranky", "five", "oil-change", "ruthie"]
    $ ruby RedisTrie.rb a
    ["apple", "auto", "automobile", "axe"]
    $ ruby RedisTrie.rb au
    ["auto", "automobile"]
    $ ruby RedisTrie.rb aux
    []
```

Read more on Tries at [Wikipedia's entry on Tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

You will definitely want to optimize your suggest method to not return ALL values, instead only returning the first X values it finds.  It would defeat the purpose to iterate the entire data structure.

Comment: Hi alex, Thanks for your answer. My next question would this have good performance or would you implement it differently. I want it to scale well. Thanks

Comment: The add_word method is pretty close to what I would deploy with.  You may want to adjust the regular expression if you are inserting more complex words.  I would probably downcase all strings as they come in, depending on how it's to be used.

As I mentioned in the post, I would also tweak suggest to stop as soon as it gets X results.  You don't want it processing the whole Trie when you pass it a blank string.

Comment: I think the above ruby code uses an old version of redis. Instead of 'zset_add' and 'zset_range' the commands for newer versions should be 'zadd' and 'zrange'.

Answer (score 6):

I also found this snippet when reading Simon Willison's impressive [Redis tutorial](http://simonwillison.net/static/2010/redis-tutorial/).

### [Solution:](http://groups.google.com/group/redis-db/browse_thread/thread/42ab3746be2ebaa5)

> Hello Max,
>
> KEYS is not the way to go, the best
>   thing you can do is to use instead a
>   sorted set. What you want is to turn
>   the first 4 or 5 characters of the
>   strings into an integer (you can
>   imagine every char as a digit of a
>   radix 256 number for instance, but
>   there are better representation) and
>   add all your usernames into a sorted
>   set.
>
> Then using ZRANGEBYSCORE you can get
>   all the elements between a given
>   range.
>
> This method is much more scalable as
>   it's an O(log(N)) thing.
>
> I'm covering this stuff in my very
>   slowly evolving Redis book...
>
> Cheers, Salvatore

Answer (score 4):

Here's a dead simple algorithm in PHP for alphabetical autocomplete with redis:

```php
function getNextChar($char) {
    $char++;
    if(strlen($char) > 1) { $char--; }
    return $char;
}

function createDictionary($redis, $key, $wordList) {
    if(!$redis->exists($key)) {
        foreach($wordList as $word) {
            $redis->zadd($key, 0, $word);
        }
    }
}

function getLexicalAutocomplete($redis, $dictionaryKey, $input) {
    $inputNext = substr($input, 0, -1) . getNextChar(substr($input, -1)); //ab -> ac

    $redis->zadd($dictionaryKey, 0, $input);
    $redis->zadd($dictionaryKey, 0, $inputNext);

    $rangeStart = $redis->zrank($dictionaryKey, $input)+1;
    $rangeEnd = $redis->zrank($dictionaryKey, $inputNext)-1;

    $autocompleteResults = $redis->zrange($dictionaryKey, $rangeStart, $rangeEnd);

    $redis->zrem($dictionaryKey, $input);
    $redis->zrem($dictionaryKey, $inputNext);

    return $autocompleteResults;
}

$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('', 0); //Your redis server ip/port goes here

createDictionary($redis, "dict", array("alfred", "joel", "jeff", "addick"));
$result = getLexicalAutocomplete($redis, "dict", $argv[1]);

echo json_encode($result);
```

Based on the article [Auto Complete with Redis](http://antirez.com/post/autocomplete-with-redis.html) by Salvatore, except I hax the need to generate an additional autocomplete dictionary, at the expense of a tiny little bit of performance penalty (a couple of zadds and zrems extra) but in most cases it should perform well. The script assumes phpredis, but it should practically be the same with predis.

Output examples:

```
> php redisauto.php a
["addick","alfred"]

> php redisauto.php ad
["addick"]

> php redisauto.php al
["alfred"]

> php redisauto.php j
["jeff","joel"]

> php redisauto.php je
["jeff"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a port of original antirez's Ruby implementation in Python:

```
http://www.varunpant.com/posts/auto-complete-with-redis-python
```

Comment: The following links will be useful to understand the context of the code : http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/autocomplete-with-redis.html, https://patshaughnessy.net/2011/11/29/two-ways-of-using-redis-to-build-a-nosql-autocomplete-search-index